# DJango - NoReverseMatch Error - What is wrong?

Tags: django

I am trying to set up a user password change from built on [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/04/django-tip-9-password-change-form.html). Unfortunately, on success, this tutorial just returns the user to the change password form, which doesn't seem very satisfactory. So, I am attempting to redirect the user user to a **success** template.

My code is in an app called *your_harmony*

**base.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'your_harmony',
    ...
    ]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^your-harmony/', include('your_harmony.urls')),
    ...
    ]
```

**your_harmony/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'password/$', change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'password_changed/$', password_changed, name='password_changed'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('password_changed')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    url = 'registration/change_password.html'
    return render(request, url, {'form': form})


def password_changed(request):
    url = 'password_changed.html'
    return render(request, url, {})
```

When I use the form to change the password and submit, the password is changed correctly, but I get the error

> NoReverseMatch at /your-harmony/password_changed/

However, when I hover over the link to call the change password form, the url displayed in the browser is

> 127.0.0.1:8000/your-harmony/password

Can someone please point what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
from django.urls import reverse

return redirect(reverse('password_changed'))
```

after your success

and in your urls.py

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'password_changed/$', views.password_changed, name='password_changed'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that makes no difference. Still get same error :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use namespaces

```
include('your_harmony.urls', namespace='whatever')

...
def f():
    return redirect(reverse('whatever:password_changed'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I stll get the error NoReverseMatch at /your-harmony/password_changed/

Reverse for 'your-harmony' not found. 'your-harmony' is not a valid view function or pattern name.